# Deleting nodes from a tree in Python

Tags: python

Below is a program I am working on that creates a tree and then can delete nodes from the tree. Im having trouble understanding just how deleting a node works and am looking for a bit of guidance. Currently My code replaces the node with the left most leaf, but Im trying to get it to delete the whole thing like it was never there. This is the area I am running into confusion with. Can someone explain?

```
    def remove(self, data):
        if self.root and self.root.data == data:  # special case for removing the root
            self.root = self.root.delete()
            return
        else:  # general case, removing a child node of some parent
            parent = self.root
            while parent:
                if data < parent.data:
                    child = parent.left
                    if child and child.data == data:
                        if child.left == None and child.right == None:
                            parent.left = None
                            return
                        if child.left == None:
                            parent.left = child.right
                            child = None
                            return
                        if child.right == None:
                            parent.left = child.left
                            child = None
                            return
                        left_most = child
                        while left_most.left != None:
                            second_left = left_most
                            left_most = left_most.left
                        child.data = left_most.data
                        second_left = None
                        return
                    parent = child
                else:
                    child = parent.right
                    if child and child.data == data:
                        if child.left == None and child.right == None:
                            parent.right = None
                            return
                        if child.left == None:
                            parent.right = child.right
                            child = None
                            return
                        if child.right == None:
                            parent.right = child.left
                            child = None
                            return
                        left_most = child
                        while left_most.left != None:
                            second_left = left_most
                            left_most = left_most.left
                        child.data = left_most.data
                        second_left = None
                        return
                    parent = child
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample input and show us the comparison between the actual output you get and the expected output you want?

Comment: What type of tree is this? AVR Binary Search? min_heap? max_heap?

Comment: I added a sample input and output. Hopefully it explains it a little better.

Comment: What *do* you expect the `11` to be replaced by? Do you want it to delete the whole subtree rooted there (so that `21` would have no nodes on the left)? Or do you expect it to preserve the order of the elements (in which case you need `11`'s right sub-tree's leftmost value or the left sub-tree's rightmost value.

Comment: I am looking for a way  to make it remake the whole tree without the deleted node, so it would be preserving all the other input numbers like the deleted one was never there.

Comment: That's not specific enough. Different kinds of trees remove elements in different ways. You need to figure out what you want the actual structure to look like after the removal, then you can try writing code to bring it about. There are a lot of options. The two I mentioned in my previous comment are probably the easiest, but they're not the only ones. Other options could try to keep the tree balanced, for instance (but you'd probably need to change other parts of your code to make their algorithms work).

Answer (score 1):

The homework assignment this question comes from links to a webpage that shows how the deletion is to be performed. Maybe you should post the entire assignment so that you can get your question answered.